# tsocks using for terminal commands

Tags: terminal, proxy, tor, privoxy

Actually, I'm using LinuxMint and would like to configure `tsocks` to use tor proxy as some repositories are banned where I am !.

I did a lot of changes in `/etc/tor/torrc`, `/etc/privoxy/config` and `/etc/tsocks.config` but no way to work and I didn't know how to reset these files to default values as it was long time ago. I tried to remove these packages and reinstall them but these files aren't removable, and I don't know if deleting them manually safe.

Then can somebody help me to re-configure them correctly to be able to use `tsocks sudo apt-get install ****` I searched a lot but nothing worked well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you try `dpkg-reconfigure <package name> ` and how do you remove it did you try `apt-get purge <package name>`?

Comment: well,that worked to re-configure them .However,now how to configure them out to use TOR ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`torrc` you should not have to mess with.

Privoxy's default `config` has a single line you need to uncomment to work with the default `torrc`.  Search in the file for "Tor".  [Details](http://www.privoxy.org/faq/misc.html):

> Since Privoxy 3.0.5, its main configuration file is already prepared
>   for Tor, if you are using a default Tor configuration and run it on
>   the same system as Privoxy, you just have to edit the forwarding
>   section and uncomment the line:
>
> ```
> #        forward-socks5             /     127.0.0.1:9050 .
> ```

`tsocks` needs to be told to use 127.0.0.1:8118 (Privoxy's port) for all addresses.

You can also try using `torsocks` which may work without configuration.

The Tor's project [page on `torsocks`](http://code.google.com/p/torsocks/) is something you should read.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `dpkg-reconfigure <package name>` to restore your package defaults.

if thats doesn't work you can purge them (purge remove the package from your PC totally including it's configs files) by using :

`apt-get purge <package name>`